# Searching for a number inside a column MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in table "recipes" called "Products". This is is filled like this:

```
460,450|50,100|243,500|141,5|457,100|383,211|
```

ProductID,ProductGrams| is the format.

Now i would like to search for an product with id  243 in the above example. How can i do this?

```
SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE Products LIKE '%243%'
```

Will also give me results if theres productgrams that are 243.

How can i do this? Im lost...

Its ok if theres also php for a solution to this.

Comment: Why are you storing two different things in the same column? This query is difficult because the data is not normalized.

Comment: Trash that table and do it the right way.

Comment: Wish i could.. if you say that to this you should see the rest..

Comment: Burn the whole thing to the ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do

```
SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE Products LIKE '243,%' OR Products LIKE '%|243,%
```

But more importantly this data should be normalized in the database prior to being queried.

Comment: I think that the '%|243%' format won't work, if the searched item is in the beginning of the row. As in the example provided, there is no | at the beginning.

Comment: Updated.  I honestly can't believe people are storing data in a database like this, it's just insane.

Comment: I know @ErikPhilips . Im just taking over some fired dudes work.. -.-

Comment: @Karem I can understand that he was fired.

Comment: %243,% will match larger numbers ending in 243, like 1243. You need to match '243,%' or '%|243,%'.

Answer (score 2):

just include the separators in your like,

```
SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE Products LIKE '%|243,%'
```

Comment: Not if its in the first place.

Comment: Remove the `|` and keep the `,`

Comment: yep you're right that it won't match items in the first position, but you can't just remove the pipe and do %243, see my comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe tthis will work?

`SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE Products LIKE '%243,%'`

Note the comma.